Extra blank space after loop in tabular
I can't understand this unexpected behavior:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcounter{i}
\newcounter{n}\setcounter{n}{3}
\def\and{&}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{c|}}
\hline
\whiledo{\thei < \then}{%
    \and\and\\\hline%
    \stepcounter{i}}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}


What's happening? Why those two vertical lines at the end?

Related/duplicates: Strange extra line after forloop in a tabular table; Extra line in a tabular using expl3 syntax

The idea behind the code I propose is basically the same as yours: we step until the desired number of cells, issuing & if not at the end of a row, \\\hline otherwise.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\grid}{O{#2}m}
 {% #1 = number of rows (by default equal to the number of columns)
  % #2 = number of columns
  \group_begin:
  \emoro_grid:nn {#1} {#2}
  \group_end:
 }

\int_new:N \l__emoro_grid_cols_int

\cs_new_protected:Nn \emoro_grid:nn
 {
  \int_set:Nn \l__emoro_grid_cols_int {#2}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{#2}{c|}}
  \hline
  \int_step_function:nN {#1*#2} \__emoro_grid_row:n
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__emoro_grid_row:n
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { \int_mod:nn {#1} {\l__emoro_grid_cols_int} == 0 } { \\\hline } { & }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\grid{3} \qquad \grid[4]{3}

\end{document}

The secret here is that \int_step_function:nN delivers the whole construct in one swoop, so after the last \\\hline there's nothing remaining. In your case you have \stepcounter{n} which produces a new cell.


Your loop structure inserts a \stepcounter in a cell after \hline, which acts like content, causing the tabular to build a new row. You'll have to find a new looping structure or technique to create what you want.
The following uses LaTeX3's \prg_replicate:nn to repeat something a number of times:

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
# Provide a user interface via \Repeat{<num>}{<stuff>}
\cs_new_eq:NN \Repeat \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcounter{cnt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | *{3}{c |} }
  a \\
  \stepcounter{cnt}% <--- this inserts a new row/cell
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{ | *{3}{c |} }
  \hline
  \Repeat{3}{& & \\ \hline}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


You may be better off employing LuaLaTeX and Lua's implementation of a while loop.

\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{c|}}
\hline
\directlua{

  i=1
  while i<=3 do
     tex.sprint{"& & \\\\ \\hline"} 
     i=i+1
  end

  }
\end{tabular}

\end{document}

Of course, for the use case at hand, a Lua for loop could be written far more compactly than a Lua while loop:
for i=1,3 do
  tex.sprint{"& & \\\\ \\hline"} 
end

